# Ingress in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I was doing some research about ingress and it seems I have to create a new ingress resource for each namespace. Is that correct?

I just created 2 separate ingress resources in different namespaces in my GKE cluster but it seems to use the same LB in(which is great for cost) but I would think it is possible to have clashes then. (when using same path). I just tried it and the first one I've created is still working on the path, the other newer one on the same path is just not working.

Can someone explain me the  correct setup for ingress?

Comment: are you using the same hostname for both ingresses?

Comment: ah yes (just *), maybe it's based on that that it uses the same LB?

Comment: We can't create multiple ingresses using the same hostname, if we do there will be a conflict. So, I'd recommend to configure different hostname for each ingress (instead of *).

Comment: Okay, and I have to create an ingress per hostname per namespace?

Comment: Exactly. Ingress is a namespace level object. If your K8s version is > 1.18.* you can use a wildcard for the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kubernetes works, ingress controller won't pass a packet to a service that is in a different namespace from the ingress resource. So, if you create an ingress resource in the default namespace, all your services must be in the default namespace as well.

This is something that won't change. EVER. There has been a feature request years ago, and kubernetes team announced that it's not going to happen. It introduces a security hole when ingress controller is being able to transpass a namespace.

Now, what we do in these situations is actually pretty neat. You will have to do the following:

1. Say you have 2 services in the namespaces you need. e.g. `service1.foo` and `service2.bar`.
2. create 2 headless services without selectors and 2 `Endpoint` objects pointing to the IP addresses of the services `service1.foo` and `service2.bar`, in the same namespace as the ingress resource. The headless service without selectors will force kube-dns (or coreDNS) to search for either `ExternalName` type service or an `Endpoint` object. Now, the only requirement here is that your headless service and the `Endpoint` object must have the same name.
3. Create your ingress resource pointing to the headless services.

It should look like this (for 1 service):

Say the IP address of `service1.foo` is `10.10.10.10`. Your headless service and the `Endpoint` object would be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bait-svc
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: bait-svc
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: 10.10.10.10
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
```

and `Ingress` resource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: ssl-certs 
  rules:
  - host: site1.training.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: bait-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

So, the `Ingress` points to the `bait-svc`, and `bait-svc` points to `service1.foo`. And you will do this for each service.

**UPDATE**

I am thinking now, it might not work with GKE Ingress Controller, as on GKE you need a `NodePort` type service for the HTTP load balancer to reach the service. As you can see, in my example I've got nginx Ingress Controller.

Independently if it works or not, I would recommend using some other Ingress Controller. It's not that GKE IC is not good. It is quite robust, but almost always you end up hitting some limitation. Other ICs are more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of conflicting Ingress routes is undefined and implementation dependent. In most cases it’s just last writer wins.

Comment: what does this suppose to mean?

Comment: It means that if you have two Ingress objects with overlapping routes, the API specification does not say which backend service will actually get used. It could be either or both, and it would still be a standards compliant implementation of an Ingress Controller.

Comment: I would say you got the question wrong. the scenario is that he has 2 services in 2 different namespaces; in which case you can't reach them both with the same ingress. So you end up creating 2 ingress resources, which feels quite wrong because you get 2 load balancers.

Comment: ingress-gcp does not create one CLB per Ingress, it does its best to combine them, give or take various Ingress-level configuration that requires more than one.

Comment: eeeeem. nope! It creates one HTTP load balancer per Ingress.